# HowTo: select all rows in a cell array, where a particular column has a particular value

Tags: octave, cell-array

I have a cell array, A.  I would like to select all rows where the first column (for example) has the value 1234 (for example).

When A is not a cell array, I can accomplish this by:

```
B = A(A(:,1) == 1234,:);
```

But when A is a cell array, I get this error message:

```
error: binary operator `==' not implemented for `cell' by `scalar' operations
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this, for a *cell array*?

Comment: `==` is not even implemented for cell-by-cell!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the expression `a(:,1) == 1234` (and also `a{:,1} == 1234`).

For example:

```
octave-3.4.0:48> a
a = 
{
  [1,1] =  10
  [2,1] =  13
  [3,1] =  15
  [4,1] =  13
  [1,2] = foo
  [2,2] =  19
  [3,2] = bar
  [4,2] =  999
}
octave-3.4.0:49> a(:,1) == 13
error: binary operator `==' not implemented for `cell' by `scalar' operations
octave-3.4.0:49> a{:,1} == 13
error: binary operator `==' not implemented for `cs-list' by `scalar' operations
```

I don't know if this is the simplest or most efficient way to do it, but this works:

```
octave-3.4.0:49> cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, 13), a(:,1))
ans =

   0
   1
   0
   1

octave-3.4.0:50> a(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, 13), a(:,1)), :)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  13
  [2,1] =  13
  [1,2] =  19
  [2,2] =  999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Octave available at the moment to try it out, but I believe that the following would do it:

```
B = A(A{:,1} == 1234,:);
```

When dealing with cells () returns the cell, {} returns the contents of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Class of `A` is `cell`. (You can see in the Workspace box).

So you may need to convert `A` to the matrix by `cell2mat(A)`.

Then, just like Matlab as you did: `B = A(A(:,1) == 1234,:);`